# ajax not getting any response from cakephp code

Tags: ajax, cakephp

I am using CakePHP 2.9 to send data on the URL using ajax and get the related response.

I tried may method to get the response, I also want to know why this `//URL:'/Pages/dropdownbox/'+id` is not working.

bellow are ajax code which I wrote in the index.ctp.

```
$("#certificatedetail").on('change',function() {
    var id = 'subcribe';
    $("#usertype").find('option').remove();
    $("#certificateclass").find('option').remove();
    $("#certificatetyp").find('option').remove();

    if (id) {
        $.ajax({
            type: 'POST',
            url:'<?= Router::url(array('controller' => 'Pages', 'action' => 'dropdownbox','id')); ?>',
            //url:'/Pages/dropdownbox/'+id,
            dataType:'json',
            cache: false,
            async:true,
            success: function(html) 
            {
                $('<option>').val('').text('select').appendTo($("#usertype"));
                $('<option>').val('').text('select').appendTo($("#certificateclass"));
                $('<option>').val('').text('Select').appendTo($("#certificatetyp"));

                $.each(html, function(key, value) 
                {
                    $('<option>').val(key).text(value).appendTo($("#usertype"));
                });
            }
        });
    }
});
```

I have written this controller code in PagesController,PHP and I declared the dropdownbox in AppController.php

```
public function dropdownbox($id = null)
{
    Configure::write('debug', 0);
    $this->layout = null;
    $this->autoRender = false;
    $category = array();

    switch ($id)
    {
        case $id == "subcribe":
            if ($id == 'subcribe') {
                $category = array(
                    'individual' => 'Individual',
                    'organization'=>'Organization',
                    'organizationgovt' => 'Organization-Govt',
                    'organizationbank' => 'Organization-Bank'
                );
                break;
            }
    }
}
```

/ bellow is the code where I specify the dropdownbox function in AppController.php

```
public function beforeFilter() {
    parent::beforeFilter();
    $this->Auth->allow(
        'login','add','index','contact','dropdownbox',
        'cityres','stateres','sectorres','productres',
        'project','service','about','apply','tender',
        'decregistration','search','searchresult',
        'tenderdetails'
    );
}
```

Comment: Your `dropdownbox()` method doesn't generate any response, you've disabled auto rendering and you're not invoking rendering (`Controller::render()`) manually, so "_not getting any response_" would be the expected behavior. Furthermore you cannot add methods to the default `PagesController` that ships with the default CakePHP app skeleton, unless you create routes that allow connecting to these actions.

Answer (score 0):

You are generating the URL on your server, and using the string literal `'id'` in it. The JavaScript `id` variable is never referenced. What you probably want is:

```
url:'<?= Router::url(array('controller' => 'Pages', 'action' => 'dropdownbox')); ?>' + id,
```

Comment: url:'/Pages/dropdownbox/'+id, 

i tried this type of url also

Comment: What does "not working" mean? Have you looked at your browser console to see if the request is going through and what response is being returned?

Comment: sir, I check my console log but its return nothing, the only ajax portion of the code is not collaborating with my dropdownbox  controller,
I don't know what's the problem but URL: not passing any data to my dropdownbox  controller

Comment: You should be able to quite clearly see from your console the exact URL that's being called and what response (including any data) that you get back. If you don't know how to find that, you're going to need to learn it before you can hope to answer the questions we need to ask to help you.

Comment: console.log(html);

this gives me nothing.

because this part of the code is not working 

type: 'POST',
                    url:'<?= Router::url(array('controller' => 'Pages', 'action' => 'dropdownbox','id')); ?>',
                    //url:'/Pages/dropdownbox/'+id,
                    dataType:'json',
                    cache: false,
                    async:true,



please help sir

Comment: That's just one part of the console. There should also be a way to watch all your network requests in real time. This is what you need to debug Ajax issues.

Comment: Can you help me in that ?

Comment: Google `monitor network requests in` plus your browser? Helping you learn that is outside the scope of this particular question.

Answer (score 0):

You are not returning any response from the controller. Do few things to debug it

1. Check in Browser's Network tab whether the called URL is correct or not.
2. Check the parameters are correct or not.

[image]
*This is how it looks in Firefox Developer Edition*

3. If URL is correct. Add below code in the **dropdownbox()** method. (Before the closing of the method)

   echo json_encode($category);
4. Check **Response** Tab in the **Network** tab. (Example image above).
5. Also, console the response in the javascript code. Maybe you will be getting some other response which is not JSON.

   success: function(html) {
       console.log(html);
       ...
   }

Hope it helps.